# Is it possible to build a .NET DLL with COM visible types without VS requiring elevation?

Tags: visual-studio, com, uac, elevation, comvisible

An assembly in a project has a type marked with ComVisible(true).

When building (non-elevated), VS tries to register that DLL and fails:

Cannot register assembly "\path\to\foo.dll" - access denied. Please make sure you're running the application as administrator. Access to the registry key 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{FFC174A1-CC90-4E25-A3F6-C30B03368250}' is denied.

We don't really want the DLL registering on the build machines. We only want to register it when we install it for the end user.

So is it possible to build without registering the DLL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So is it possible to build without registering the DLL?

Yes. In the project settings (right click, "Properties") under "Build", there is a "register for COM interop" checkbox.